# Adding testdouble to vendor bundle seems wrong

Tags: aurelia

In order for me to be able to run unit test that use testdouble I had to add it aurelia.json/vendor-bundle

I don't want test double in my released application I just needed for testing.

Is there a better way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a `env` variable that you can set to avoid this happening, did not found any docs about it unfortunately.

My entry in aurelia.json looks like this now:

```
      {
        "name": "testdouble",
        "path": "../node_modules/testdouble/dist/testdouble",
        "env": "dev"
      },
```